# Can you annotate assessments using the recaptcha enterprise v1beta1 endpoint?

Tags: annotations, recaptcha, enterprise, recaptcha-enterprise

Does the annotate feature actually work for the v1beta1 recaptcha enterprise endpoint?

The [reCAPTCHA Enterprise REST reference](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.assessments/annotate) shows the v1beta1 endpoint includes the ability to annotate assessments, but the guides say "Some features, such as the Annotation API are available only for the v1 API" and the annotating documentation only shows the v1 url.

Alternatively, is it possible to use the v1 endpoint to annotate assessments that were created with the v1beta1 endpoint?

We may not be able to use service accounts for authentication, so are just wanting to confirm our options if we can only use the v1beta1 endpoint with API keys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can annotate assessments using the v1beta1 endpoint. You can also mix and match, and annotate assessments created with v1beta1 using the v1 annotate API.